# can you "add" isomorphisms?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that $A,B,C,D$ are rings such that $A \cong C$ and $B \cong D$. Is it necessarily true that $A \oplus B \cong C \oplus D$ (, where $\oplus$ is the direct sum)?

Comment: I suspect that you mean $A \cong C$ and $B \cong D$ instead?

Comment: yes ! sorry I shall fix it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's true. Let $f \colon A \to C$ and $g \colon B \to D$ be isomorphisms. Then

$$
h \colon A \oplus B \to C \oplus D, (a,b) \mapsto (f(a),g(b))
$$

is an isomorphism (which you should verify).